# How can I create a navigation stack with TabBarViewController as the root?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

My TabBarVC is the core of my app.  I have 3 view controllers. Each view controller is "embedded" in a navigation controller.

```
TabBarVC -> UINavigationController -> HomeVC
         -> UINavigationController -> TimelineVC
         -> UINavigationController -> ConversationVC
```

I'd like my `TabBarVC` to be able to push a `InstantMessageViewController` onto its stack whenever it wants.  I understand that TabBarVC doesn't have "stack" or a NavigationController -- and that only its children have navigation controllers.

When `TabBarVC` receives a `NSNotification`, I want to push `InstantMessageViewController` onto its stack.

Maybe something like this inside `TabBarVC`?

```
let mvc = self?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! InstantMessagesViewController
mvc.user = self?.notificationUser
self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(mvc, animated: true) //it doens't work because self.navigationController is nil.
```

When the user pushes the back button, it will go back to TabBarVC.

I want to be able to push multiple `InstantMessagesViewController` onto the stack at any time and reorder them programatically.

I don't know what's the best way. Do I create a UIWIndow? Do I create a UINavigationController programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is push the `InstantMessagesViewController` on whatever `UINavigationController` that is currently selected on the `UITabBarController`.

```
// Inside your UITabBarController
if let navigationController = selectedViewController {
    let mvc = self?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! InstantMessagesViewController
    mvc.user = self?.notificationUser
    navigationController.pushViewController(mvc, animated: true)
}
```

But the proper thing to do would be to present `InstantMessagesViewController` modally (and push your subsequent `InstantMessagesViewController`s onto this `UINavigationController` stack):

```
let mvc = self?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! InstantMessagesViewController
mvc.user = self?.notificationUser
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mvc)
presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In order to dismiss this `UINavigationController` when you're on your root `InstantMessagesViewController`, try the following code inside of `InstantMessagesViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let navigationController = navigationController {
        if navigationController.viewControllers.count == 1 {
            let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "onBackTapped:")
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
        }    
    }
}

func onBackTapped(barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I don't want to push it onto the selectedViewController, since it has nothing to do with that view controller.  (They're separate concepts).  I know modally is the right way, but I need to manage a stack and let users navigate back and forth.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a UINavigationController that you present modally. This will give you the navigation stack that you desire, and the root message controller can dismiss the navController when you click a back button (which you'll have to add).

Comment: Thanks Mark. How can my root VC dismiss the navController modal?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include code you can add to your `InstantMessagesViewController` to add a custom back button.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Do you know why deinit doesn't get called when the root VC tries to dismiss? (all the others in the stack call deinit except for the first one in the stack)

Comment: Does anything retain the first view controller, or the navigation controller?

Comment: I think it's the navigation retaining it. The others get deinit fine

Comment: Potentially. But if you're concerned about solving that problem as well, you should ask another question, rather than try and solve it in the comments.